Salam alaykyum I want help will my dua and prayers be accepted though I masturbate and repent and masturbate and repent I want the answer yes or no
My name is Leo (fake name) I'm 17 I keep masturbating through I promised Allah not to do it but I done it and I feel sad and scared.
I always ask Allah the same dua. But I'm scared that it won't be accepted because I masturbate.
Please can someone help me stop and answer if masturbating will make my duas and prayers not accepted

This question is similar to: How to repent after breaking a fast by masturbation?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Allah's greatness transcends our comprehension, extending far beyond our sight and awareness. The Quran discusses the concept of making pledges, known as "Qassem," in the name of Allah to rectify wrongdoings. Failing to uphold these commitments necessitates seeking redemption, often involving a financial obligation. While Allah is indifferent to these agreements, seeking His forgiveness is paramount. This entails performing two units of voluntary prayer, providing assistance to those in need, and reciting "Lakhowla wala quwata illa billah heleliul azeem" regularly, with the hope that Allah will grant forgiveness. It's important to understand that Allah's love surpasses even that of a mother's; just as a mother wouldn't punish her child indefinitely for a mistake, Allah, too, is merciful. He is not a tyrant but the embodiment of compassion.

We are living in a world where there are restriction on marrying until some age is reached like 18 or 21. We know most reach sexual maturity much earlier than that.
Sex is a natural feeling just like our food requirement. We cannot just suppress it. The ejaculatory fluids build up over time and we need to ejaculate it to get relief. If one does not do this it can happen in sleep (nocturnal emission). So what happens in sleep will not be forbidden if done during awake. Main thing is we should not fall into doing forbidden things like adulatory. There are Islamic scholars who told something like, it is your liquid you can throw it off. But make sure you don't do it often as it can effect your normal sexual life when you marry.
Fasting is recommended for those who are not able to marry. It is not for suppressing sexuality but to train yourself so that your bodily urges do not make you indulge in doing forbidden things like adulatory.
